# Concatenate a string with curdate in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO insertlog (Inforamtion) VALUES (
concat("Row Was Inserted",curdate());
```

MySQL is returning an error, but I cannot figure out why. My google searches do not show examples on how to perform something like this.

Comment: Did you misspell your column name `Inforamtion`?

Comment: You are missing a closing )

Comment: Both was the error -.-'

Comment: what error you getting sophie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing one closing `)`

Moreover as Bill pointed, you may have spelled your column name incorrectly - `information`

Comment: @echo_Me: Yes, i just figured it out. Happens when you are using different laptop :P

Answer (score 2):

use it simpler like that

```
    INSERT INTO insertlog (Inforamtion) 
    SELECT  concat("Row Was Inserted ",curdate()) ;
```

be sure if your column is `Information` or `Inforamtion`

your query also works but you missed  `)` in the end . here demo with both solutions :

[**Demo to try here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4b06/1)